# Preterm baby which was born with (?x?) nails and hair - word request

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word for the next context.

> This is a preterm baby which was born with (?x?) nails and hair.

The word should imply that the nails and hair weren't **ready** yet, as in normal mature baby. I remember I saw word which describes it. What about undone? Does it fit the context? I think this is the word I saw in past, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Undeveloped? Partly developed? Incomplete?

Comment: What about undone? Does it fit the context? I think this is the word I saw in past, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It could also be **unformed**. But we shouldn't be guessing at the word you can't remember.

Comment: undone is a [synonym](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/undone) for  some of the words suggested here by others

Comment: @green_ideas  No.  "undone" implies that the baby has some sort of control or choice over the growth of hair.  It isn't a useful synonym in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "undone"

"Immature", "underdeveloped", "partly formed" or (turning the meaning round) "developing": these are all possible words.

Not really about an English adjective, but preterm babies are often covered with body hair called lanugo. So perhaps the expression should be

> This is a preterm baby which was born covered with lanugo